# CSS issue with mobile: Blog page appearing too narrow

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design, width, blogs

Got a weird issue only affecting one page. I'm currently in the process of redesigning a WordPress site and everything on mobile is fine. With one exception. The blog archive page (http://aeworldwidelimo.com/blog/). It's appearing too narrow at least on my iPhone 6. Now the individual blog posts are just fine. It's just this one page causing the headaches.

I thought it might be something in the sidebar but after changing widget-area to 100% width, nothing changed. So it's really odd that this one template isn't complying. Anyone got an idea as to why?

Answer (score 0):

It's the width you've set for .wrapper that's doing it:

```
.wrapper {
    width : 90%;
}
```

Delete that width setting it works.

Comment: I just deleted it but I see no change. Can you check on your end, just in case it's caching?

Comment: Yes, I just rechecked it, and (at mobile widths) the main content box, with white background, is narrower than the gray header area. But if I delete the width setting on the .wrapper rule then the content box lines up correctly with the header on both sides. I think you're right in suspecting a caching problem. Nice looking site, by the way!

Comment: Thanks for the compliments. Yea, you just can't completely win on those caching plugins.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source code of your blog page your have some syntax blips lines 223-225. It's not immediately obvious to me if this would be related to your problem though I didn't see it on other pages I checked and it wouldn't hurt to fix it anyway.

Good luck

[image]

Comment: You know what that is? It's legacy code from when this site was on HubSpot. I should delete all references of it although I'm agreement it probably won't have an effect on the layout issue. Thanks.